# “The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.”

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I have a DLL written in Delphi 7 that I need to use in Visual C++ 2008.

From documentation that came with DLL, I can see that function is declared as (Delphi 7):

```
function ReadInfo(pCOM, pBuf, pErr: Pointer):boolean;
```

where **pCom** is pointer to data structure:

```
TCOM = record
dwBaudRate: Longword;
nCom,
nErr,
nLang : Byte;
end;
```

**pBuf** is pointer to "array of byte" (as it is written in DLL's documentation).

**pErr** - not used.

So now in c++ (after successfully loading DLL with LoadLibrary), I call:

```
myFunc = (MY_FUNC_POINTER)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "ReadInfo");
```

which also doesn't return any errors.

MY_FUNC_POINTER is defined as:

```
typedef bool (*MY_FUNC_POINTER)(TCOM*, BYTE*, void*);
```

where TCOM is:

```
struct TCOM
{
     unsigned long dwBaudRate;
     BYTE nComm;
     BYTE nError;
     BYTE nLanguage;
};
```

I defined:

```
TCOM MyCom;
BYTE *myRes;
myRes = new BYTE[1024*1024];
```

But after calling

```
myFunc(&MyCom, myRes, NULL)
```

I get “The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.” error.

Comment: Is there a calling convention mentioned in documentation of that Delphi function ?

Comment: No, all information from documentation is given in my question - nothing else :(

Comment: Then we can only guess if that function really uses `register` calling convention (which is a calling convention used if you don't explicitly specify any) or if that it's a poor documentation (and they forgot to mention such crucial information).

Comment: If the DLL was intended to be portable (callable from other languages) you can try declaring `typedef bool (__stdcall *MY_FUNC_POINTER)(TCOM*, BYTE*, void*);`

Comment: @David Heffernan: Please read carefully. Delphi uses register calling convention by default, but you can change this (specially if you're developing a DLL). And yes, I noticed that the function declaration doesn't specify any calling convention...

Comment: @jigsore When you don't specify a calling convention, as is the case here then register convention is used. I'm not sure where you get the idea that the code in the question uses stdcall. I read carefully like you said but could not find any reference to stdcall.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: most developers who are competent enough to write portable DLLs understand the difference between calling conventions, and know that `cdecl` and `stdcall` are the only portable conventions, and tend to favor `stdcall`. But many people who write documentation are not competent enough to document such convention usage. Sad.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Looks like you are right. It's hard working with inaccurate details, but I guess I should have enough experience now to anticipate such things. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would appear to be a calling convention mismatch. On the face of it, the function declares no calling convention in the Delphi, so the default Borland register convention is used. Your C++ code does not declare a calling convention for the import so the default of cdecl is used. But it is plausible that the Delphi code and documentation are not aligned and the Delphi code actually uses a different calling convention. Check the Delphi code, or contact the vendor. No matter what, the error message that you report does indicate a binary mis-match across the boundary between your module and the other  module.

If the function really does use the Borland register calling convention (but see below for more), then you cannot readily call the function from languages other than Delphi. In that case you'd need a bridge to adapt that to a standard calling convention such as stdcall. By that I mean a Delphi DLL that can call the original DLL and expose it's functionality a way suited to interop. A  better solution would be to fix the root problem and build the DLL again using standard calling conventions.

---

In fact, I now suspect that all the other commentators are correct. I suspect that the Delphi documentation does not match the Delphi code. I suspect that the function really is `stdcall`. So you can, probably, solve your problem by changing the function pointer typedef to be as follows:

```
typedef bool (__stdcall *MY_FUNC_POINTER)(TCOM*, BYTE*, void*);
```

My reasoning for this is that in `stdcall` the callee is responsible for cleaning the stack. That's not the case for `cdecl`, and since all the parameters, and the return value, fit in registers, it's not the case for Delphi register calling convention, for this function. Since there is a stack pointer mis-match, it follows that the most likely explanation is that the Delphi function is `stdcall`.

All the same, it's not comfortable to be working out calling conventions this way. If you cannot get any help from the DLL vendor then I'd be inclined to dig a little deeper by looking at the DLL function's code under a disassembler.

Comment: Thank You for your answer - I will try to create "bridge DLL" as you suggested, as I don't have access to original dll's code.

Comment: This assumes the DLL really is using the `register` convention and not the `cdecl` or `stdcall` convention. Since the documention does not say, all you can do is guess. Only an analysis of the DLL's assembly code can reveil the actual convention used. I would complain to the DLL vendor for better documention.

Comment: @Remy What do you mean? The code is clear. Since no calling convention is specified, the default of register is used. You might as well complain that I'm assuming that the function has three parameters.

Comment: I think Remy's point is that it's very believable that the documentation is incomplete, that the *real* declaration of the function should specify a different calling convention, that the calling convention is specified in the Delphi units, but omitted from the documentation for brevity. But in that case, just look at the Delphi unit instead of the documentation to see what calling convention it uses.

Comment: @hvd I get that. My answer now says that. I tend to be quite literal and assume that the information provided is accurate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: then you give documentation writers too much credit :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't draw a distinction between documentors and coders because they are the same people where I work which seems like the sanest approach.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: In a lot of places I have heard about, the coders are not always the documentors. And even when the coders are the documentors, they sometimes forget to document things like calling conventions, or they don't account for their DLLs being used by other people in the future. Just saying, in my experience, documentation is very hard to trust, and I have run into my share of documentation mistakes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Mine is always bang on. :-)